# Drawing grids with predefined outlines

Tags: tikz-pgf, grids

I use the following code from the answers to [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/628385/drawing-a-square-grid-with-a-default-size-more-than-1) and [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/632011/pentominoes-shapes-filling-pentominoes-boards) to fill rectangular grids with predefined shapes.

**Is it possible to fill grids with predefined outlines, other than the default rectangular shape; for example as in the included lower picture!**

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper, left=10mm, right=10mm, top=8mm, bottom=15mm}
\begin{document}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\lwdth}{.3mm}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\opc}{0.6}
\def\refpnt{%
\fill[black] (0,0) circle [radius=4pt];
}

%begin defining fill colours ==========================
\tikzset{%
filrd/.style={% 
fill=red},
filgr/.style={%
fill=green},
filbl/.style={%
fill=blue},
}
%end defining  fill colours ==========================
%begin defining grid ==========================
\newcommand\sqw{1}
\tikzset{
pics/square/.default={\sqw},
pics/square/.style = {
code = {
\draw[pic actions, draw=none] (0,0) rectangle (#1,#1);
}}}%draw=none is to avoid displaying the little squares outline

\renewcommand\sqw{1.4}
%end defining grid ==========================
%begin defining pentoshapes solution ==========================
\tikzset
{%
%
pics/pent-W/.style={code={\draw[xscale=#1, filrd] (1*\sqw,0*\sqw) |- (0*\sqw,1*\sqw) |- (1*\sqw,3*\sqw) |- (2*\sqw,2*\sqw) |- (3*\sqw,1*\sqw) |- cycle;
\refpnt
}},%
pics/pent-W/.default={1},%
%
pics/pent-Z/.style={code={\draw[xscale=#1, filbl] (1*\sqw,0*\sqw) |- (0*\sqw,2*\sqw) |- (2*\sqw,3*\sqw) |- (3*\sqw,1*\sqw) |- cycle;
\refpnt
}},%
pics/pent-Z/.default={1},%
%
pics/pent-L/.style={code={\draw[xscale=#1, filgr] (0*\sqw,0*\sqw) |- (1*\sqw,4*\sqw) |- (2*\sqw,1*\sqw) |- cycle;
\refpnt
}},%
pics/pent-L/.default={1},%
}%
%end defining pentoshapes solution ==========================

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1, transform shape, fill opacity=\opc, line width=\lwdth]
\draw[step=\sqw] (\sqw,\sqw) grid (15*\sqw, 16*\sqw);
%
\node at (4.5*\sqw,10.5*\sqw) {\huge\bf W};
\pic [rotate=90] at (5*\sqw,7*\sqw) {pent-W};
%
\node at (7.5*\sqw,11.5*\sqw) {\huge\bf Z};
\pic [rotate=0] at (6*\sqw,8*\sqw) {pent-Z};
%
\node at (9.5*\sqw,13.5*\sqw) {\huge\bf L};
\pic [rotate=0] at (10*\sqw,9*\sqw) {pent-L={-1}};
%
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: You mean a `\clip`?

Comment: @– Symbol 1 No, I mean defining a grid with a specific outline.

Comment: What about `\pgfdeclarepatternformonly`?

Comment: @– Symbol 1 I have a limited programming capabilities. Would you please post an answer with your idea applied to my code! Thank you.

Comment: The built in grid for TikZ always produces rectangle and always starting at (0,0).  You can use a scope and \clip to limit the visible portion.  Alternatively you can use `\foreach` or matrix to create your own grids.

Comment: @– John Kormylo I have a limited programming capabilities. Would you please post an answer with your ideas added to my code. Thank you.